# Second opinion on shower leak

Tags: shower, leak

A leak on the ceiling was found and it seems to be coming from the shower that is right above it on the third floor. So far I have been told it needs to be re grouted. The tile on the shower floor does look messed up.

My question is, how could it be leaking if it has a liner? Has anyone experienced anything similar?

Some water damage on the wall:
[image: water damage on the wall]

Comment: This is a problem you need to find where and what is leaking before guessing at repairs.  Water damage on the shower wall(no picture yet) might be a pipe leaking or maybe even a roof leak.  Water can travel some distance before it finds something to stain.

Comment: Are you 100% certain that it has a liner or other waterproofing membrane? If the water is leaking from upstairs and only coming out here, the water could be coming from darn near anywhere, maybe even a roof leak. Also, I'm pretty certain that fixing grout won't fix a leaking shower pan...

Comment: Also won't fix a broken/cracked pipe or joint in the drain or supply plumbing, for that matter. Isolating the actual point of leakage is key to not doing a dozen different things that cost money but don't actually solve the problem.

Comment: This is the shower on the third floor above the ceiling leak? That yellow streak that extends above your photo appears to be from the water leak. This suggests that the leak has a contribution from above the photo. Shower leaks are usually down low, so that's odd. Where are the valves relative to this evidence? How high does that streak go? Additional images please.